# GCML Prediction Error 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: google-cloud-ml

An initial call (after every few hours) to the "Online" prediction services of GCML always results in Server Error 502. After a few minutes, the same request succeeds.

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 502 when requesting https://ml.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<project-name>/<model-name>/versions/<version-name>:predict?alt=json returned "Bad Gateway"
```

Why does this happen ? Is it that every time a request made to the model the restored session is cached so subsequent calls succeed while the initial call fails? How can this service be used for RRS (Request response service)

[Update]

Now getting 502 error on all the prediction services. Even for models which  were working before. Have tried local prediction on the models which work correctly

Comment: We will investigate the error you are getting on all of your models. I presume this occurs, even after "warming up" the model for several minutes? Can you confirm?

Comment: yes. Still getting the same error. thanks!

Comment: If you send a detailed message to cloudml-feedback@google.com with your model and version names, we can help identify the problem. Thanks.

Comment: sure, will do it shortly [update] done, sent the message